# Can't manage to position elements

Tags: css, position, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I have a Span tag containing a IMG tag and another Span tag.
I would like the inner Span tag to be aligned to the left and the IMG tag to be centrally aligned plus I want both the tags to be vertically aligned in the middle, and I can't seem to get this right...

This is how it looks (It's blue because the outer Span tag is marked in FireBug to show that it's stretching the entire surface):

[image]

As you can see in the image, both tags are centred and they are also aligned in the top of the container, I don't want either of this.

This is the markup:

[image]

This is the current CSS of the tags:

```
.v-button-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 15px 0 9px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

.v-icon {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

.v-button-caption {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I left out the CSS that isn't relevant for my problem, colors, font-specs and such. Needless to say I'm no ace at CSS. And I've looked up several guides covering the problem, but I've only managed to find examples where the entire content of a div is centered, and that's not what I want.

Does anyone with good CSS knowledge see the problem in my code? Or have another solution to solve my problem..?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here's a screen shot of the entire layout due to request. Sorry I have to blur some things... but they are in either case not important. =)

[image]

**EDIT2:** I did manage to solve my problem using the following CSS:

```
.v-button-details-panel-header .v-button-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: inherit;
    padding: 0px;
}

.v-button-details-panel-header .v-button-wrap .v-button-caption {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}

.v-button-details-panel-header .v-button-wrap .v-icon {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I'm sure the advice [dgvid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9897/dgvid) proposed would have been good for a static layout. But since the panels and horizontally stretched buttons move depending on expansion and collapsing that wasn't a fitting solution.

Comment: It's really difficult to make out the image you posted. Perhaps a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve would help, along with an HTML snippet we can copy/paste.

Comment: I can post a screenshot. Posting the HTML will be pretty hard.. you see I'm developing in Vaadin (GWT like framework) and I have really no control over the markup, it gets generated from java code, and the markup I can see in FireBug is crazy hard to work with. Tags on tags on tags.... so the small HTML snippet I've already added is pretty much all I can get. However, this snippet that is posted should be the only thing that impacts the positioning I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to set the CSS `display` property of both your img and span.v_button_caption to `inline-block`.

See also this article: [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

As for another technique to achieve the desired result: If you know the height of the container element and you know the height of the element to be centered (and unfortunately from the CSS you've posted, it does not appear that you do), then you could

1. Give the container element CSS property `position: relative'
2. Give the element-to-be-centered CSS property `position: absolute`
3. Set the CSS `top` property of the element-to-be-centered to (containerHeight / 2) - (centeredEltHeight / 2).

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at this. on my way from work now so I can't test it right away... I recognize Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content", I came across it in my own research, guess I'll look over it again! but I'll me back on Monday trying it out

Comment: Good article.  That's very useful.